# What is the purpose of an ICollection in a POCO (EF) class?

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

What is the purpose of the `public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }` in a POCO class?

```
public class Category
    {
        [ScaffoldColumn(false)]
        public int CategoryID { get; set; }

        [Required, StringLength(100), Display(Name = "Name")]
        public string CategoryName { get; set; }

        public virtual ICollection<Product> Products { get; set; }


    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Products` related to the `Category` will be lazy loaded by Entity Framework when the property is accessed the first time.

How you can load related entities is explained in more detail in [Loading Related Entities](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj574232.aspx):

> Lazy loading is the process whereby an entity or collection of entities is automatically loaded from the database the first time that a property referring to the entity/entities is accessed. When using POCO entity types, lazy loading is achieved by creating instances of derived proxy types and then overriding virtual properties to add the loading hook.

So Entity Framework will derive a proxy class from the `Category` class and override the getter of the `Products` property to load the related products the first time the property is accessed.

Comment: Is this considered efficient/Correct?  I guess my point is i am trying to think of effective ways to utilize this but don't if it is considered a good practice?.

Comment: This is how you do lazy loading of related entities in Entity Framework. If you don't want to do lazy loading (perhaps for performance reasons or simply because you dislike the concept) then you should use eager or explicit loading. More details in the linked documentation.

Comment: You can also eager load using these properties, which are known as "Navigation Properties".